# Retweet for Android API problems

Tags: android, api, oauth, twitter4j

Hello all and first thing to apologize for my poor English.

I wanted to comment my problem on the attempt of the integration retweet on my android application.

So far I managed to authenticate with OAUTH and even I have been able to send a tweet.

My problem starts when I want to be able to send retweet from a ID that I have saved in a class.

I have tried almost everything, Ive been dozens of hours looking for information on this, but without knowing if I on the right track.

- trying to create a getRetweetsById function
- trying  to make http GET to the address:
  https://API.Twitter.com/statuses/retweets/21943348.json

... getting the same response in all cases

It doesnt work.

If someone could guide me which is the appropriate method and the steps i should follow I would be eternally grateful.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey try following code

Twitter mTwitter = TwitterFactory.getInstance();

mTwitter.retweetStatus("send ur id here");

thanks
santhu